# Punta Cana travel

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, dominican-republic

I'm a US citizen. My parents are visiting me from India.They have a valid Indian passport with US tourist visa. We are planning for a week long trip to Punta Cana in April. My parents will exit USA and get back to USA with me.

In this case, do they need to get a Dominican Republic Visa?

Answer (score 1):

Indian citizens who have a valid US visa do not need to get a visa for Dominican Republic. You can enter for up to 90 days.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states for Indian passport holders:

> Passport required.
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for the period of intended stay.
> - Warning: if departing from the USA (regardless of any destination passport exemptions), a valid passport and/or accepted departure document is required by the US immigration authorities.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Romania, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State traveling as tourists for a maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> Warning:
>
> - Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.
> - Exempt are holders of foreign passports stating Dominican Rep. as place of birth.